# Draw path in the scroll view performance

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, quartz-graphics, draw

I have a view inside `UIScrollView` which has `CATiledLayer` (mapView).

Map can be scaled and scrolled.

The method `viewForZoomingInScrollView`: of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` returns mapView. On top of that view (inside `UIScrollView`) I had another view (overlayView) where I need to draw number of paths (`CGPath`, up to 40). But the performance in this case is quite bad. How can I improve it? What is the right way to draw on the scroll view?

What I’ve already tried to do:

1. I’ve tried to render on the view’s context in the `drawRect:` and `drawLayer:inContext:` methods ( in this case I need to keep constant size of the `overlayView`,  otherwise it crashed when zoom is too big – but this means that I need to redraw each time user scrolls or zooms). In this case the app is kind of slow even though the time for drawing all paths I have is about 0.02 sec.
2. Tried to do `overlayView` as `CATiledLayer`, but in this case original mapView became very slow. Tiles of  overlayView loaded only after all tiles from the mapView are loaded.  It looks like all instances of `CATiledLayers` use the same thread for rendering or somehow blocks each other.
3. Tried to draw each path in a separate view with `CAShapeLayer`. Very slow, I think it is because of big overhead with view drawing.